# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service name True must be a quoted string, i.e. 'True'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, coreos, jwilder-nginx-proxy

My docker-compose.yml looks like the below. When i run docker-compose up I get the below error.

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', the service name True must be a quoted string, i.e. 'True'.

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    container_name: pleroma_postgres
    networks:
      - pleroma
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    image: pleroma
    container_name: pleroma_web
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=<myplaceholderhost>
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=4000
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=<myplaceholderhost>
      - LETENCRYPT_EMAIL=<myplaceholderemail>
    expose:
      - "4000"
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/pleroma/uploads
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx: 
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    networks:
      - pleroma

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:v1.5
    container_name: letsencrypt
    volumes_from:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /apps/docker/articles/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html

networks:
  pleroma:
```

My docker version is

> Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

My docker compose version is

> docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306

Running CoreOS version 1911.3.0

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: What might cause this issue and how do I go about remedying it? I can't seem to find any documentation on this at all.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/
I suggest you look at the part about the key format

Comment: https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion the docker compose v2 and v3 syntax might vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue by modifying the nginx and letsencrypt portions of my docker-compose.yml file to be as follows.

```
 nginx: 
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    labels:
      - "NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=true"
    networks:
      - pleroma

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:v1.5
    container_name: letsencrypt
    environment:
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /apps/docker/articles/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /apps/docker-articles/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

It seems "volumes_from" is deprecated in docker-compose v3. As well as I had forgotted quotes around my label and needed to set my environment within letsencrypt.

Answer (score 0):

in CentOS env your `.yml` file directory must be `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by saying that the .yml file needs to be in the above folder?